# bokeh select widget callback using CustomJS to filter dataframe and plot

Tags: javascript, python, callback, bokeh

I want to add callback to my bokeh select widget using CustomJS .I need to filter my dataframe according to callback from select widget. Since am a novice to JavaScript programming i havent been able to write the code for the callback

```
    true_source=ColumnDataSource(data={'a':df.loc[, 'MONTH_YR'],
                            'b':df.loc[, 'MCOUNT'],
                            'qty':df.loc[,'MPDCQTY'],
                            'value':df.loc[,'MQTYRATE'],
                            'section':df.loc['MSECTION']})

    #I added the true_source so I could have a reference from my original dataframe while filtering

    source=ColumnDataSource(data={'x':df.loc[df['MSECTION']=='TURRET','MONTH_YR'],
              'y':df.loc[df['MSECTION']=='TURRET', 'MCOUNT'],
              'qty':df.loc[df['MSECTION']=='TURRET','MPDCQTY'],
               'value':df.loc[df['MSECTION']=='TURRET','MQTYRATE']})

    def callback_select(attr, old, new):
        s=section.value
        new_data={'x':df.loc[df['MSECTION']==s, 'MONTH_YR'],
                  'y':df.loc[df['MSECTION']==s, 'MCOUNT'],
                  'qty':df.loc[df['MSECTION']==s,'MPDCQTY'],
              'value':df.loc[df['MSECTION']==s,'MQTYRATE']}
        source.data=new_data
```

Since i want to deploy a HTML file, writing the callback in python wont work.
So i tried writing the callback using CustomJS.
But am sure i wrote it wrong.

```
    callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ts=true_source), code=""""
                    var data1=ts.data;
                    var section=data1['section']
                    var a=data1['a']
                    var b=data1['b']

                    var data=source.data;
                    var f=cb_obj.value;

                    var x=[];
                    var y=[];
                    var j=0;

                    for(var i=0;i<section.length;i++){
                        if(section==f){
                        x[j].push(a[i]);
                        y[j].push(b[i]);
                        }   
                    }   
                    source.change.emit();    
                            """)
```

[this image here shows the plot, select option dosent work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNdef.png)

Can anyone help me with this JS code?

Comment: You are making and populating some local variable lists `x` and `y` – and then immediately throwing them away. For them to have effect, you need to use them to set `source.data` to be a new dict. It's not clear exactly what you are trying to do, so it's hard to be more specific. You almost certainly also want `if(section[i]==f)` instead of what you have now.

Comment: those **x** and **y** are the keys for source.I want to update them based on the **if(section___)** condition .

Comment: All I want is to rewrite the def callback_select() in JavaScript .Those x and y are supposed to be the source ColumnDataSource keys. I saw somewhere that the keys to be updated need also be initialized someway within CustomJS, so thats what i am trying to do which i totally have done wrong here.

Comment: You've skipped the last part of `callback_select` which is the crucial bit: You need something like `source.data = new_data` but you don't. You are never actually updating `source`, which is why nothing is changing.

Comment: I understood somehow ....maybe a lathargic way but yes i got the solution thanx

Comment: Glad to hear!  If you put your solution in an answer I will upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the callbcak in python as mentioned in question one can create similar in CustomJS for implementing in htmls.Here **var x, y, qty, value** are keys for source and **a, b, qty, value** are for true_source. I updated for source using them.

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source,ts=true_source), code="""
                    var data=ts.data;
                    var section=data['section'];

                    var a=data['a'];
                    var b=data['b'];
                    var qty_t=data['qty_t'];
                    var value_t=data['value_t'];

                    var data1=source.data;
                    var f=cb_obj.value;

                    var x=[];
                    var y=[];
                    var qty=[];
                    var value=[];

                    for(var i=0;i<a.length; i++){
                        if(section[i]==f){
                          x.push(a[i]);
                          y.push(b[i]);
                          qty.push(qty_t[i]);
                          value.push(value_t[i]);

                        }
                    }
                    data1['x']=x;
                    data1['y']=y;
                    data1['qty']=qty;
                    data1['value']=value;

                    source.change.emit();
            """)
```